# In Haskell, why is it important to use Eq a => [a] before a function such as below?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the function

```
sameElts :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
```

that, given a list, returns True when all elements of the list are equal, and returns False otherwise.

For example:

```
sameElts [1,2] = False
sameElts [2,2] = True
sameElts [2] = True
```

Can anyone explain the need for the code fragment `Eq a =>` in the type of `sameElts`? I assume that it enforces the type to be a number list so to use equals operators.

Comment: When pattern matching over `Int` the code actually translates to using `==` to check if the input number matches the pattern number, e.g. `sameElts [1,2]` becomes something like `sameElts [x, y] | x == 1 && y == 2`. We *could* define `Int`s in a way that your definition doesn't require `Eq`, for example `data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat` but then you have to write `sameElts [Succ Zero, Succ (Succ Zero)]` etc.

Comment: `Eq a` is a constraint on your type.  My preferred way of explain constraints is thus:  If you say you have a function `sameElts : [a] -> Bool` (no `Eq` there) then I should be able to give you a list of any type, such as `CrazyFooBarThing` which you _can not _ inspect in any way and you must still give me a sensible result.  Can you do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Eq a =>` snippet just requires the type `a` to be *in the type class* `Eq`, which basically means there has to be an equality test for that type. This allows you to use the `==` and `/=` operators.

Numbers, for example, have an implementation for `Eq` via the standard library (Prelude), but other types too. You could also create custom data types and define an equality check yourself. This makes `sameElts` very generic, since it will work for any type in `Eq`.

Comment: Importantly, functions are not in `Eq`, so if you have a list like `[(+), (-), (*), (/)] :: [Num a => a -> a -> a]`, the `sameElts` function wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Without the `Eq a` constraint, the `sameElts` function wouldn't know *anything* about the type of the values in the list. In particular, it wouldn't even know if/how to compare the elements for (in-)equality.

Adding the constraint means that only lists of values which are of some type instantiating the `Eq` class (i.e. values which can be compared for equality) can be passed to `sameElts`, and `sameElts` knows that it can call all the functions part of the `Eq` class on the values (e.g. `==`).